# Number of strings of length $n$ over {$x,y,z$} where $x$ and $y$ appear at least once

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, combinatorics-on-words

What I did so far, using generating function:

$[x^n] (x+x^2+\dots)(x+x^2+\dots)(1+x+x^2+\dots) = \frac{x^2}{(1-x)^3}= x^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty {3+k-1 \choose 2} x^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {2+k \choose 2} x^{k+2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {k \choose 2} x^{k}$.

I am unsure about the last step and realized that this method would only count strings without considering an order. How do we make sure that order is considered? I thought we would need to use a weight enumerator as shown [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emhaiman/math172-spring10/ordinary.pdf) on page 2 but then I don't know what exactly I should do. Please note that I want to solve using generating function first and only then try using recursion.

Comment: Inclusion exclusion seems simpler.

Comment: @lulu can you please explain how to use it here? I don't see it. Also, it was part of the exercise to use generating functions

Comment: I don't understand.  Just the usual method...count the total, subtract those with no $x$, subtract those with no $y$, add back those with neither $x$ nor $y$.

Comment: @lulu oh right, idk how I missed it. Still they are asking to do it using generating functions too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we talk about strings then the **arrangements** of letters in the string or sequence **matters**.However, if you use ordinary generating functions as you did your works, you cannot take the arrangements of letters into account, you can just find the number of sets that contain desired number of elements.

Then, we need something else here. It is [exponential generating functions](https://www.math.brown.edu/mchan2/2019Spring_2520/StudentPresentations/George_Exponential_Generating_Functions.pdf).It is said that $x,y$ must appear at least once,then

- E.G.F for $x$: $$\frac{a^1}{1!}+\frac{a^2}{2!}+\frac{a^3}{3!}+...=(e^a-1)$$
- E.G.F for $y$: $$\frac{a^1}{1!}+\frac{a^2}{2!}+\frac{a^3}{3!}+...=(e^a-1)$$
- E.G.F for $z$: $$1+\frac{a^1}{1!}+\frac{a^2}{2!}+\frac{a^3}{3!}+...=e^a$$

For example, if you find the number of strings of length $n$ that obey the rule:

$$\bigg[\frac{a^n}{n!}\bigg](e^a-1)(e^a-1)e^a$$ or

$$n!\bigg[a^n\bigg](e^a-1)(e^a-1)e^a$$ or by using $$(e^a-1)(e^a-1)e^a=e^{3a}-2e^{2a}+e^a$$ It gives $$3^n-2\times2^n+1^n$$

Comment: thank you very much! very helpful:) and thanks for the source!

Comment: @strugglingmathguy you are welcome :)

Comment: Back in full force, I see ! $\;\;$ :)

Comment: @trueblueanil thanks a lot :))